# In C++ map, which is better for usage/perfomance and conforms to the guidelines, using find_if or find then and .at

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a C++ map, in which I need to search for an element then get the element if it is exist.

The first way to do that is using find

```cpp
if (mymap.find(mykey) == mymap.end()) 
{
    //return error code
    return ERROR_CODE;
}
else
{
    value = mymap.at(mykey).second;
    return SUCCESS_CODE;
}
```

second way to do that:

```cpp
auto iter= find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), [&key](auto &item){return item.first == key;})
if(iter == mymap.end())
{
   return ERROR_CODE;
}
else
{
    value = iter->second;
    return SUCCESS_CODE;
}
```

Is there any technical consideration or guidelines (like cpp guideline) that mention something like that, which way is better?

Comment: The complexity are the same. So the first one is better because it's more readable.

Comment: How about number 3?
`auto iter = mymap.find(mykey); if (iter != mymap.end()) value = iter->second;`? It's only one lookup that way.

Comment: @Yves: No, `map::find` is logarithmic, whereas `std::find`/`std::find_if` are linear.

Comment: @Jarod42 So you mean the performance of `std::find` on `std::map` is worse than `map::find`?

Comment: @Yves: `map::find` is better than generic `std::find` (as map use the fact that data are sorted).

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't understand what you said: `std::find`/`std::find_if` are linear because now we are searching element into a `std::map`. As my understanding there shouldn't be any difference, unless `std::find` converts `std::map` into a `std::vector` and do the search, then it's linear.

Comment: @Yves Please note the complexity and type requirements sections at [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) cppreference pages. `std::find` is supposed to operate on input iterators, wihile `std::map::find` is (can be) optimized for that particular data structure.

Comment: @Yves `std::find` is basically just a for loop over the iterators, it'll have to test every element in the map until it finds the matching one. `std::map::find` can traverse the tree (or whatever data structure the map is implemented with) and find the element in logarithmic time

Comment: @Bob__ So are you saying if we do `std::find(mymap.begin(), mymap.end()...);`, there would be a conversion from `map::iterator` to the input iterator, and traversing a map with the input iterator will have a linear complexity?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Do you mean that when we use `std::find` on a `std::map`, the algorithm of `std::find` will ignore the order of the elements in the map and just check every element one by one so the complexity will be linear (just like `std::find` on a `std::vector`)?

Comment: @Yves yes, `std::find` is always linear, it doesn't know anything about the containers it's operating on

Comment: @Yves No, I'm saying that the algorithm used by `std::find` doesn't *require* any iterator more "sophisticated" than an input iterator, because it uses only the `!=`, `*` and `++` operators of any passed iterators. [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) requires a forward iterator, because it uses `<` and has the additional semantic requirement of the range beeing sorted, so that it can apply an algorithm with logarithmic complexity. `std::map::find` *knows* exactly on what data structure is applied, so it can exploit its characteristics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use `std::find_if` which is linear, whereas you might have iterator in logarithm time. You might do

```
auto it = mymap.find(mykey)
if (it == mymap.end()) 
{
    //return error code
    return ERROR_CODE;
}
else
{
    value = it->second;
    return SUCCESS_CODE;
}
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta: indeed

Comment: Aside: In C++ 17 and later, I'd move the initialiser into the `if`

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that if `map.find` wasnt as good as or better than the generic algorithm then it wouldn't exist in the first place. Eg there is neither `std::vector::find` because it cannot be better than `std::find` nor `std::list::find` because it would be just as poor as using `std::find` on the list.